# How to parse this text in a cleaner way in Python?

Tags: python, string, parsing

I am just learning Python, and I am wondering how to parse this text in a cleaner way.

```
text = '/category/Women-Makeup?size=OS'
```

The result I am trying to get is

- category = 'Women'
- sub_category = 'Makeup'

This is the code I came up with.

```
category = text.replace('/category/', '').split('?')[0].split('-')[0]
subcategory = text.replace('/category/', '').split('?')[0].split('-')[1]
```

Hope this question is not too basic.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the general format?

Comment: This is a job for regular expressions (the "re" module). To learn and play with them there is https://regex101.com/ (set to Python flavor).

Comment: Take a look at stdlib [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the format of the text is constant as displayed here, you can use regular expressions to parse the text using rules and retrieve the results:

Here, the following sets up two capture group (sets of parentheses) to capture the pattern described in your post:

```
>>> cat, sub = re.findall('/\w+/(\w+)-(\w+)', '/category/Women-Makeup?size=OS')[0]
>>> cat
'Women'
>>> sub
'Makeup'
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your `text` elements look like the one in your example, try this:

```
target = text.split('/')[2].split('?')[0].split('-')
print('category:',target[0],'\nsubcategory:',target[1])
```

Output:

```
category: Women 
subcategory: Makeup
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format of "text" is always '/category/...-...?size=OS'.
You can try the following code:

```
category = text[10:text.index('-')]
subcategory = text[text.index('-')+1:text.index('?')]
```

I always try to find unique symbol when i write code, such as, "-","=","?".
text.index() can find the index of first occurrence you want.